# NSArray Count returning long int?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, count, nsarray, long-integer

Im making a simple NSArray, then getting a random Index from that array and storing it as an int, however im getting a warning saying it should be a long int, even though im only expecting it to return 0, 1 or 2. Not that its an issue, but i cant understand why.

```
NSArray *randomWordList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello", @"Test", @"Send", nil];  
int randomWordIndex = rand() % [randomWordList count];`
```

Comment: Technically, `count` returns an unsigned long, and by the usual rules of integer promotion that would make the result of `%` long.  Objective-C is kind of random with regard to complaining about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSArray's `count` method returns `NSUInteger` which is a `unsigned long` for 64-bit builds. The reason the compiler is warning you is because `int` holds a smaller range of numbers than `long`, so it is warning you of potential loss of data.

Just change `int randomWordIndex` to `NSUInteger randomWordIndex`.

Comment: Thanks, im following a book thats now outdated for xcode, is this a new feature or did they make the same mistake?

Comment: `NSUInteger` was introduced in Mac OS X 10.5 I think.

Comment: thanks again, i was just curious, i made it a long int and it stopped complaining, just wanted to know why :)

Comment: Indeed NSUInteger was introduced with Leopard, however, I doubt the indexes were ever of `int` type since `int` is signed; would be waste of memory

Comment: You should make it `NSUInteger` as @dreamlax suggested, not `long int`

Comment: Yes, pre-`NSUInteger` (and hence pre 64-bit), `-count` was `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast it. You must agree that the compiler can't know the elements count since the array is dynamically allocated so it simply assumes the largest value, which is a NSUInteger.

Comment: In my opinion, casting should be avoided, it is better to use the correct type for `randomWordIndex`, especially in this scenario when the `randomWordIndex` will likely be provided to `objectAtIndex:` which expects `NSUInteger` to already.

Comment: Yes of course, but if he really wants an `int`, he could cast it :)

Comment: @dreamlax - The odd thing is that if you assign `length` directly to an `int` the compiler won't complain.  It's only when you do an operation on the value first.  And you've got to admit that it's unlikely that an NSArray will ever contain more than 2 billion entries.